# Serialize XML file in the below format

Tags: vb.net, xml-serialization

well i have a class that i have to serialize in the following format which i don't know i've tried googling but nothing found so i needed some help from you experts :)

```
    <XmlRoot("plist")> Public Class Plist

    Private _Elements() As Item = Nothing
    <XmlArray(ElementName:="Elements")> _
    Public Property Elements As Item()
        Get
            Return _Elements
        End Get
        Set(value As Item())
            _Elements = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Structure Item
        <XmlElement("key")> _
        Dim Key As String
        <XmlElement("value")> _
        Dim Value As String

        Public Sub New(_Key As String, _Value As String)
            Key = _Key
            Value = _Value
        End Sub
    End Structure
End Sub
```

and got the XML output as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Elements>
        <Item>
            <key>key1</key>
            <value>val</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <key>key2</key>
            <value>value</value>
        </Item>
    </Elements>
</plist>
```

But i want it like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Elements>
        <key>key1</key>
        <value>val</value>
        <key>key2</key>
        <value>value</value>
        <key>key3</key>
        <value>value</value>
    </Elements>
</plist>
```

Anyone can help me ?

> PS: Sorry if im wrong :(

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you cannot have that. You can only have 1 keyword element within an element: key & value are 2 different elements within the same "Elements" element. That's why your output puts the item element as a solution.

Comment: Thats not valid xml - you would need to roll your own Serializer. Or whack the guy wo '"invented" your format

Comment: Sorry guys, basically it's from the itunes XML request while buying app ! i just want to deserialize it ! :) thank you though !

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm in agreement with @Djerry.  It is most certainly valid XML (though poorly-designed, perhaps), but XML serialization isn't necessarily capable of reading *every* schema out there.  This, to me, looks like a format with which the XML serialization would *not* be capable of working.  At least not through the standard serialization attributes.  I would recommend looking into reading this data through some other means, such as `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`.

Comment: If you must use serialization, you'll probably need to implement your own custom serialization via the `ISerializable` interface.